# Marketing cloud - SOAP API ContinueRequest - Error - Missing action

Tags: soap, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to call soap api and since the number of records is more than 2500 , i have to use ContinueRequest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"> will insert token here</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ContinueRequest>will insert req id here</ContinueRequest>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
      
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am getting following error . My first call gave 2500 records, and now i need remaining records, but i am getting following error response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1fdaa145-96de-40bb-81c2-35a36112c840</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6247ea86-37ff-4b51-be6a-527b203b412e">
                <wsu:Created>2023-04-24T01:07:47Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2023-04-24T01:12:47Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
            </soap:Code>
            <soap:Reason>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="en">WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is missing: action.</soap:Text>
            </soap:Reason>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I dont want error response but a soap message with remaining records . what am i doing wrong in the request message

Answer (score 0):

Since i was using postman, i had to add soap header to header section. Please note not in payload , but in seperate header section. rest message was ok